# Order automorphisms of rationals

Tags: order-theory, rational-numbers

Is it right that all order automorphisms of rational numbers have form $~~f(r) = ar+b; ~~ a,b\in \mathbb{Q}; ~~ a>0$?

As i know all order automorphisms have form $f(n) = n +k; ~~ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so a question about rationals arose.

By order automorphism i mean such bijective map $f: ~~ \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}~$ that  $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{Q} ~~ (x \leq y) \rightarrow (f(x) \leq f(y))$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, just take a continuous, piecewise linear increasing function with rational coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

No, we can easily find piece-wise linear examples. A simple example would be to make $f(r)=ar$ when $r\geq 0$ and $f(r)=a'r$ when $r<0$, with $a,a'>0$.

You can construct much more complicated examples - any (non-empty) interval of the form $(p,q)$ is order-isomorphic with any other, and any interval of the form $(-\infty,p)$ is order-isomorphic with any other, then if $p_1<p_2<\dots < p_n$ are rationals there is an order-automorphism of $\mathbb Q$ which sends $i$ to $p_i$.

Comment: Are there any order isomorphisms which are not piece-wise linear maps?

Comment: @exitingcorpse's answer would imply that there are, but that the piecewise linear examples are somehow "dense" in the set of all such examples, but I don't know the details of that.

Comment: @Igor I know I'm 7 years late but I ran into into this question while looking for examples of non-piecewise-linear order automorphisms of the rationals and it was surprisingly hard to find anything, so I'll leave this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1941112 this gives a non-piecewise linear (non-linear and smooth over the reals so hence non-piecewise linear) increasing bijection (and hence order automorphism) of $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1):

Thomas is right, you have piecewise linear examples, and the group is uncountable. There is a remark in Cameron's Permutation Groups book where he states that the closure of the piecewise linear order automorphisms is the entire group.

Comment: Closure in what topology? Pointwise convergence might lead to irrational functions ... Or does he just say that the piecewise linears are dense in the group?

Comment: he just states it as a remark, so i'm not sure. i just recall reading it (and looking at the book, he doesn't state anything more)

Comment: Could someone provide an example of an order isomorphism (of rationals) which isn't piece-wise linear, please? I'll be very grateful!

Comment: this .pdf might point you in the right direction of what to search for http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/articles/dm13.pdf